# Video player not working on samsung smart tv

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv

Here i created a sample application for samsung smart tv using TV SDK 5.1.Thsi cide works well on 5.1 emulator.and is not playing he video on the actual device.Is there any additional code is needed for this work on the actual device?

```
Main.onLoad = function()
{ 
  plugin = document.getElementById("plugin");

  plugin.Open('Player', '1.112', 'Player');

  plugin.Execute("InitPlayer", "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4");
  plugin.Execute("SetDisplayArea", 10, 10, 100, 100);
  plugin.Execute("SetInitialBufferSize", 400*1024);
  plugin.Execute("StartPlayback");
  console.log("Main.onload end");

}
```